# Un-Wrap or De-Inherit an object

Tags: python

A code block I do not have access to, returns an object that is "wrapped" or rather inherited from a base class, that I want to recover. The wrapper is harmful, I want to get rid of it. Is there a way to upcast to the parent class? To unwrap the object? To disinherit it?

I prepared a simple example: Is it possible to manipulate the `u` object in a way that it will be a `Person` object and say hello in  a nice way?

```
class Person():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def say_hello(self):
        print("Hi, my name is " + self.name)

class Unfriendly_Person(Person):
    def say_hello(self):
        print("Leave me alone!")

u = Unfriendly_Person("TJ")
u.say_hello()
```

Comment: `super(Unfriendly_Person, u).say_hello()`

Comment: Yes, that's it. Super frustrating how much I'd been looking into solutions with the super keyword and not come across this construct. Thanks!

Comment: @python_user, post it as an answer, maybe?

Comment: @MatBBastos it is mostly a dupe

Comment: Note: If you want to remove the derived class's method for _all_ instances you can simply `del Unfriendly_Person.say_hello`.

Answer (score 1):

You might assign to `__class__`, so

```
class Person():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def say_hello(self):
        print("Hi, my name is " + self.name)

class Unfriendly_Person(Person):
    def say_hello(self):
        print("Leave me alone!")

u = Unfriendly_Person("TJ")
u.__class__ = Person
u.say_hello()
```

output:

```
Hi, my name is TJ
```

But rememeber that this will jettison *all* methods from `Unfriendly_Person` even these not defined in `Person`.